# Decorating an HTML element using prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to extend/decorate an HTML DOM Element using following code:

#### HTML

```
<div id="count">42</div>
```

#### JS

```
function decorateElement(element) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.prototype = element;

    obj.getCount = function () {
        return this.innerHTML;
    };

    return obj;
}

var elem = decorateElement(document.getElementById('count'));
```

My reasoning was that, when a JavaScript property is accessed, if it is not found in the immediate object, it will be searched along the prototype chain. I came to this (wrong) conclusion reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and many others.

And, this does not seem to work as I intended:

```
// expecting 42
console.log(elem.getCount()); // prints 'undefined'

// expecting 42
console.log(elem.innerHTML); // prints 'undefined'
```

How can I extend/decorate a DOM element using prototypal inheritance? I do not want to pollute the DOM element by injecting functions to itself like this:

```
var elem2 = document.getElementById('count');
elem.getCount2 = function () {
     return this.innerHTML;
}
console.log(elem2.getCount2()) // prints '0'
```

Comment: Is there a special reason you are going through all this trouble to get the innerHTML or are you just trying to better understand prototypal inheritance?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: `innerHTML` is just an example. I want to know if I could add my own functionality to DOM Elements, much like classical inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need the getCount function to get the innerHTML of the element that is being passed in the decorateElement function, just modify the getCount function in the following way:

```
obj.getCount = function () {
        return element.innerHTML;
    };
```

Explanation: Use "element" instead of "this", because if you use "this:, then inside the function "this" will be in the context of the function decorateElement, and it will look for the innerHTML property for that function which does not exist.